# How do I get proguard working with sjersey?

Tags: json, scala, jersey, proguard

Trying to use Jersey with Scala, via [a fork of SJersey](https://github.com/GrahamLea/sjersey), and obfuscating it with ProGuard.

I've got all of this stuff:

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Signature,InnerClasses
```

and I'm doing this:

```
-keep public class com.example.*JsonSeralisedClasses {
    public *;
}
```

but when I encode stuff with jersey nothing comes out!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out eventually that SJersey doesn't use public methods, but introspects onto private fields, so one needs to do this:

```
-keep public class com.example.*JsonSeralisedClasses {
    public protected private *;
}
```

See **protected private** is the difference.

Alernatively, you can annotate everything with @BeanProperty (which makes public accessors that are preserved using the original config).